# Need to refresh the page to see a YouTube live event that has just begun

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, ytplayer

I’m using YT.player to show live events on the website : http://www.solarimpulse.com/rtw

Since youtube changes the display of live event the countdown on the YT.player is not dynamic anymore. I need to reload the page to see the countdown going down. And worse than that when I start the live event nothing append in the player, I need to reload the page to see the video.

Last year the countdown and the player was working fine, I didn’t change the code since then :

```
        var player = {
            playVideo: function (container, videoId) {
                if (typeof(YT) == 'undefined' || typeof(YT.Player) == 'undefined') {
                    window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = function () {
                        player.loadPlayer(container, videoId);
                    };
                    $.getScript('//www.youtube.com/player_api');
                } else {
                    player.loadPlayer(container, videoId);
                }
            },
            loadPlayer: function (container, videoId) {

                youtubePlayerSatcom = new YT.Player(container, {
                    playerVars: {
                        controls: 1,
                        rel: 0,
                        autoplay: 1,
                        playsinline: 1,
                        modestbranding: 1, // disable watch on youtube
                        fs: 1, // fullscreen
                        cc_load_policy: 0,
                        iv_load_policy: 3, // annotations
                        showinfo: 0 // don't show loading
                    },
                    height: '100%',
                    width: '100%',
                    videoId: videoId,
                    events: {
                        'onStateChange': function (event) {
                            if (event.data === 0) {
                                youtubePlayerSatcom.loadVideoById(videoId, 0);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                });
            }

        };

        player.playVideo('satcom-player', videoId);
```

How can I fix that ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: where is the countdown  ?

Comment: It appear when the video is not already playing. example : http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/image.php?id=e691fd1

Answer (score 0):

I made a small fix to reload the video if it hasn't started yet. It's not very clean as the player get black and load again but it works. The countdown get dynamic like that.

```
  $.doTimeout('youtube_notplaying', 20*1000, function () {
        if (typeof youtubePlayerSatcom != 'undefined') {
            if (youtubePlayerSatcom.getPlayerState() == -1) {
                if (debug_interface) console.log('load '+videoId);
                youtubePlayerSatcom.loadVideoById(videoId);
            } else if (youtubePlayerSatcom.getPlayerState() != -1) {
                return false; // stop timeout
            }
        }
        return true; // repeat
    }, true);
```